# looping arrays, 2 fields in one button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, forms

I've searched some answers and found one but doesn't really say the code but logic which is nice. But I've yet to make it right, and I've attempted many tries.

So It's the shopping cart, I put my items into a session variable (array). And in my shopping cart page I have 2 forms per row (edit quantity and delete item). What I am trying to do is make the over-all button into one.

So when change any quantity fields (or checking 'delete item' boxes), if I click to that one submit button it will update all instead of my one form per action.

***So here is my original code: (***EDITED see the last 3 form of the post)

What I've attempted (one of those) to do is make the cartOutput loop into just one form, having one submit button... then for each field will be an array. I think it can be done that way, but I can't make it, I changed my field into 'quantity[]' and 'item_to_adjust[]' to have an array input, and I edited my php action, adding another for loop

here's my code for that:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
          $i++;
          while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_adjust) {
                      foreach($cart_items_new as $item_id => $quantity) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
                      }
                  } // close if condition
          } // close while loop
} // close foreach loop
```

And yes, it doesn't work, it submits but does nothing, please forgive me for being messy.

Edit: 
(When the user adds a new cart item)

```
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
$pid = $_POST['pid'];
$wasFound = false;
$i = 0;
// If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) { 
    // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
    $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
} else {
    // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
          $i++;
          while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
              if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid) {
                  // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                  array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                  $wasFound = true;
              } // close if condition
          } // close while loop
       } // close foreach loop
       if ($wasFound == false) {
           array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
       }
}
header("location: cart.php"); 
exit();
}
```

(View and render cart, I'll just include the edit and delete part)

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'><font face='Verdana'>Your shopping cart is empty</font></h2><br>";
} else {
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $details = $row["details"];
            $quantity = $row['quantity'];
        }

//EDIT
$cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post">
    <input name="quantity" id="price" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" class="form-control input-xsmall gitna"  maxlength="1" />
    <center><input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change"  class="btn btn-primary"/></center>
    <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
    </form></td>';

//DELETE
    $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><center>
<input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="X" 
/></center><input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form>
</td>';
```

Then after Submitting, here's what happens:

```
        if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && $_POST['item_to_adjust'] != "") {
    // execute some code
    $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $quantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $quantity); // filter everything but numbers
    if ($quantity >= 100) { $quantity = 99; }
    if ($quantity < 1) { $quantity = 1; }
    if ($quantity == "") { $quantity = 1; }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_adjust) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
    } // close foreach loop
}
```

Comment: Just an idea: Make a new submit form. Catch the form submit with jQuery and stop it from doing anything (preventDefault). Next make the function submit all other forms with .submit()

Answer (score 0):

#### Structure of your session

Store your items in the session indexed by the item id.

```
$_SESSION['cart_array'][ $itemId ] = $quantity;
```

You save the items like this, which makes it more cumbersome to access the items in the cart

```
$_SESSION['cart_array'][0] [ 'item_id' ] = $itemId;
$_SESSION['cart_array'][0] [ 'quantity' ] = $quantity;
```

#### Build your form

Make your cart **one** form.
For each entry create an input field in a way like this

```
print '<form action="cart.php" method="post">';
foreach ($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $itemId => $quantity) {
  // query product information from database here

  // build form row with one input field for each entry in the cart
  print '<tr>';
  print '<td> add product information here </td>'
  print '<td><input name="quantity['.$itemId.']" value="'.$quantity.'"></td>';
  print '</tr>';
}
print '</form>';
```

#### Add item to cart

After submit of your form you can loop through the quantities array you received via post and update your session data

```
// check if cart already exists. if not, init it.
if (!isset(_SESSION['cart_array']) {
   $_SESSION['cart_array'] = array();
// otherwise save itemIds and their quantities
} else {
  foreach ($_POST['quantity'] as $itemId => $itemQuantity) {
    // if the given quantity is 0 remove the item from the cart
    if ($itemQuantity == 0) {
      unset($_SESSION['cart_array'][ $itemId ])
    // otherwise save or update the quantity for the given item
    } else {
      $_SESSION['cart_array'][ $itemId ] ['quantity'] = $itemQuantity; 
    }
  }
}
```

#### Add delete buttons to the form

If the rest is working you can add delete buttons. The buttons have to set the value of the corresponding input field via javascript to 0 and submit the form.

Comment: I can't make it to work, I adjusted also the names so it would fit my code, but after submit there's no error but nothing happens. May I ask if you can adjust the names that would fit my code. I can post other infos of my code if you need so.

Comment: Could you post a dump of your session and the post array after submit? <?php print '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); print_r($_SESSION); ?>

Comment: I'm sorry, I already edited my answer but forgot to reply in comments, thank you.

Comment: Um, hello? somebody help?

Comment: I edited my answer to make my points clearer. Hope it makes it easier for you to understand the approach.

Comment: Thank you sir Jens for the patience and the will to help. It's been several days since I'm adjusting my code and applying this logic, but my head really hurtsss reallyyyy. I kind of understand the logic.

Comment: But here's how I need to store my session variable's

**$_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));**
And I use this code to update: **array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));**

Comment: Why do you need to store the session variables like this? As said in my answer you make it more complicate than needed. In other words, the key to simplicity is to use the $pid as index in your session array. You still use a counter as index which forces you to loop through your arrays instead of directly accessing the fields.